# Edit tags in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

it's my first time using powershell and I don't get the solution for my problem :/

I have following xml file:

```
<mockup>
 <controls>
  <control>
   <controlProperties>
    <text>Löschen</<text>
   </controlProperties>
  </control>
  <control>
   <controlProperties/>
  </control>
  <control>
   <controlProperties>
    <text>Abbrechen</text>
   </controlProperties>
  </control>
 </controls>
</mockup>
```

I have 100s of these files with about 100 text tags within. I want to translate those text-tags. Therefor I go through all files, go through all text-tags and check if the value is for example "Löschen" and change it to "Delete".

I've tried lot of things (without xml it worked already, but it would mess up my xml file if I don't constrain it to the text-files.

My last try is this one:

```
$file = gi *.bmml
$pattern = 'Löschen'
$xml = [xml](gc $file)
$xml 
Foreach ($control in $_.mockup.controls.control) |
   Foreach {$control.controlproperties.text.Replace $pattern "Delete"
$xml.Save($file.Fullname)
```

I would appreciate your help, I'm really tired and go to sleep now. Maybe someone can give me a good tutorial for xml handling for my case (there are 1000s but none for my case).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Foreach ($control in $_.mockup.controls.control)
```

Should be:

```
Foreach ($control in $xml.mockup.controls.control)
```

Also the approach you are taking to replace text isn't going to work. Try this:

```
Select-Xml $xml -XPath '//text' | Foreach {$_.Node.InnerText = 'Delete'}
$xml.Save("c:\somepath.xml")
```